# Wordpress wp_nav_menu how to add scripts in to list items

Tags: wordpress, menu, wordpress-theming

This is my original list Menu which inlude the scripts.

```
<li>
<a href="/" data-start="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);" 
                data-300="color: rgba(160, 199, 52, 1); ">Home
</a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="/blog" data-start="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);" 
                data-300="color: rgba(160, 199, 52, 1); ">Blog
</a>
</li>
```

I was currently rewrite the menu using wp_nav_menu:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'Header' ,
                  'container' => '') ); ?>
```

*
May I know how to include the scripts

```
data-start="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);" 
data-300="color: rgba(160, 199, 52, 1); "
```

in the wp_nav_menu 's list items???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with [Walker](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker) create own class and extends Walker_Nav_Menu